# Programmatically Moving PDFs to SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, pdf, microsoft-graph, vba

I have been stumped on this problem for far too long and wanted to reach out for help. I want to programmatically move PDFs from a local shared drive to a SharePoint 365 document library.

I currently use VBA to move excel workbooks to a SP 365 doc library, and I have attempted to use similar code to move the PDFs using a FileSystemObject variable and the Microsoft Scripting Runtime/Microsoft Scriptlet Library references checked off.

VBA has no trouble moving the PDFs from one shared drive location to another, E:/Test1/TestPDF.pdf to E:/Test2/TestPDF.pdf for example, but when replacing a local drive address with the SharePoint URL in the destination path as I would for an excel workbook, I receive a Run-time error '52' Bad file name or number message:

```
Dim InputPath as String, OutputPath as String, Example_PDF as FileSystemObject

Sub SharePoint_Save_PDF

Set Example_PDF = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

InputPath = "E:\Test1\Example.pdf"
OutputPath = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleSubSite/ExampleDocLibrary/Example.pdf"

Example_PDF.CopyFile InputPath, OutputPath

End Sub
```

I have also tried using the following:

```
OutputPath = "\\example.sharepoint.com\sites\ExampleSubSite\ExampleDocLibrary\Example.pdf"
```

but I get Run-time error '76' Path not found.

From previous internet research, it appears that utilizing a Power Automate flow would require either an on prem data gateway installed, which is restricted by my organization, or using OneDrive as a middle ground, which I would definitely want to avoid.

I have also tried to explore the Microsoft Graph API functionality, but I admit this is currently outside of my comfort zone and existing skillsets.